# Explaining accelerating spacetime expansion?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, differential-geometry, space-expansion

I should begin by noting that I am NOT a physicist, I study differential geometry and so my physics background is extremely limited. That being said I was reading a textbook on general relativity and found the idea of the expansion of the universe and the cosmological constant rather interesting. I study a lot of hyperbolic manifolds, and although it is generally not considered that the universe has negative curvature, is it possible that constant expansion could appear as though it is accelerating in a hyperbolic universe? In other words, could the universe be expanding at a constant rate, but negative curvature induces a psuedo-acceleration that is caused by contraction of lengths and negative curvature?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you want to know, but accelerating cosmologies in standard FLRW universes have a time-dependent metric whose dynamics is determined by the energy-momentum tensor of the cosmic fluid. The standard model is flat (i.e. has zero curvature), but the scale factor appearing in the metric has accelerating expansion nevertheless.

Comment: Cosmological data prefers a flat universe as you said. You can probably create such expansion effect by inducing a negative curvature but that would probably alter many cosmological observations...

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of the universe is about the expansion of space, not space-time. If you work with a [Friedmann model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation) with $\Omega_k > 0$ the geometric will be hyperbolic. You may want to follow the suggestions in the designated section of the referenced article.

Comment: @AFG Thank you for the edit.